# DX11 add a simple black box on a texture

Tags: directx-11

I want to add a simple black box(like this: [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMnuQ.jpg)) on a texture(ID3D11ShaderResourceView), is there a simple way to do it in DX11? don't want write a shadow to do it.

Comment: If you want a one-pixel border, just draw 4 lines over the image. See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Simple-rendering)'s ``PrimitiveBatch``

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you're trying to do is actually "initializing texture programmatically". Textures from D3D POV are nothing more than pieces of memory with clearly defined layout. Normally, you create a texture resource, read data from a texture file (like *.BMP for example), put the data in the texture and then feed it to the pipeline for sampling.

In your case though, you need an additional step:

1. Create texture resource using either D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT or D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC flag - so you can access it from the CPU
2. Read the color map to your texture
3. Depending on the chosen type, either add your data to the initial data or Map/Unmap and add your data (by your data I mean overwrite each edge of the image with black color)

This can be also done to kind of "generate" textures, like for example checker-board or clouds.

All the information you need can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476905(v=vs.85).aspx).